# Compilar Arquivo .ly

Tags: haskell

Eu estou compilando um programa em Haskell, mas veio um arquivo `.ly`, e eu não consigo compilar ele. Eu tento 
ghc Grammar.ly

E recebo a mensagem:

```ly
ld: warning: ignoring file Grammar.ly, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x3E 0x20 0x7B 0x0D 0x0A 0x3E 0x20 0x6D 0x6F 0x64 0x75 0x6C 0x65 0x20 0x47 0x72 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): Grammar.ly
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ZCMain_main_closure", referenced from:
      _main in ghc11930_2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Se eu tentar com `ghc -c -O Grammar.ly`, recebo a mensagem:

```
Warning: the following files would be used as linker inputs, but linking is not being done: Grammar.ly
```

ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.

Comment: Para essas perguntas de erro de compilação, quanto mais informação melhor. Em particular, apresentar o código que você está usando para que possamos reproduzir seu problema ajuda bastante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arquivos fonte haskell notmalmente tem a extensão `.hs` (para arquivos Haskell normais) ou `.lhs` (para arquivos "literate", em que o padrão para cada linha é ser um comentário e linhas de código são marcadas com `>`).

Esse arquivo `.ly` que você tem na verdade é uma descrição de gramáticas para o gerador de parsers [Happy](https://www.haskell.org/happy/). Seguindo a tradição do yacc, um gerador de parsers para C que usava a extensão `.y`, os arquivos de entrada do Happy vém com extensões `.y` ou `.ly` (para a versão "literate").

Para compilar o seu arquivo de gramática [simplesmente use o happy ao invés do ghc](https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-invoking.html).

```
happy Grammar.ly
```

A saída deve ser um arquivo "Grammar.hs" que você deve passar pro ghc. Para mais informações, consulte a [documentação do Happy](https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/index.html).